# nikon d7100 shutter activation but no picture

Tags: nikon

Recently I tried to take a photo with my Nikon D7100. The shutter activated but no picture was stored. I tried again and got the same result. I then switched the camera off and then back on and it seems to be working correctly now. The shutter count is 42,200.
Anybody have any ideas?
Cheers
Ian

Comment: I have no idea about that particular event, but it might be worth checking your firmware versions and updating if not current.

Comment: Does an image come up while buffering? My wife’s mom’s Nikon by default shows the taken image while it’s being saved (at least, I believe it does this from the buffer). I’m trying to ascertain if the image is lost at the buffer or at the sd/cf card.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Hueco, I switched that function off to save battery life. It's the first time that this has happened, I think?. The SD card is about two thirds full and I only use the cards once.

Comment: Is the D7100 capable of mirror lockup? Does cycling the power automatically cancel mirror lockup?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen the same issue with a D7100 (& Nikkor 18-140mm ) this week. Just as described the D7100 operated as normal and it continues to increment the image numbers. Lucky for me I spotted this early. I removed the battery and removed both Sandisk SDHC cards. After replacing the battery and then the 2 SDHC cards normal operation resumed. I am on the current firmware and lens profiles. The recorded image files have a gap of about 25 frame numbers, so some aspect of the D7100 believes it is working - but it had failed to write the missing NEF file to either of the SDHC cards.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to:
- Check thoroughly the integrity of the memory card. Re-format, if you think it is a healthy card;
- Update firmware if possible;